# hide (forever) specific updates in Windows 10? HP Printer update failure

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

As you can see in the screenshot below, my system attempts (multiple times per day) to install an HP printer update that will never work. How do I stop this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following link, microsoft kb3073930 gives you a tool to prevent updates.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

Comment: Which is talked about in the accepted answer on the marked duplicate. ;)

Comment: page didn't refresh so there was no answer when i posted

Comment: No big deal, just pointing it out to others that may come along to vote on keeping it open or not. :)